# How to join two tables with grouping in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables,Table 1 and Table 2,Accid is the key to join two tables,
i want to sum revenueact and revenuutilz based on year and account, so out will look like this
[image: output]

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

in reality more data is there,when i join two tables and group by year only first account is coming,can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
    Accname,
    YEAR,
    SUM(revenueact) AS  Revac,
    SUM(revenuutilz) AS Revut
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
ON a.Accid = b.Accid
GROUP BY Accname,Year
```

Comment: thanks , i did't know that i we can group by two columns,i was simply trying to group by  name.

Answer (score 1):

You cound use a join adn a group by

```
 select t2.accname, sum(t1.revenueact), sum(t1.revenuutiliz), t1.year
 from table1 t1
 inner join table2 t2 on t1.accid = t2.accid
 group by t2.accname, t1.year
```

Comment: `t2.name` should be `t2.accname`

Comment: thanks , i did't know that i we can group by two columns,i was simply trying to group by name